# Expected parenthesis errors gfortran

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran, parentheses

I am trying to compile some fortran code using gfortran v.4.8.2.
When I compile, I get the following errors:

```
ant_driver.f90:185.72:

 if (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,ns)
                                                                    1
Error: Syntax error in IF-expression at (1)
ant_driver.f90:187.119:

ry%thck(ew,ns) = -rhoo/rhoi * (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-   model%climate%eus(ew,
                                                                       1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
ant_driver.f90:188.27:


endif
                           1
Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1)
ant_driver.f90:248.82:

odel%geometry%usrf(ew,ns) = - (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,
                                                                       1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
ant_driver.f90:260.107:

model%geometry%usrf(ew,ns) - (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,
                                                                       1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
ant_driver.f90:174.30:

 call glide_set_eus(model,eus)
                     1
Error: Rank mismatch in argument 'inarray' at (1) (scalar and rank-2)
```

The errors relate to the following lines of code:
185-188:

```
if (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,ns) < 0 .and.    model%geometry%thck(ew,ns) == 0 .and. &
                        mask(ew,ns) == 1) then
                            model%geometry%thck(ew,ns) = -rhoo/rhoi * (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,ns))
                    endif
```

248:

```
model%geometry%usrf(ew,ns) = - (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,ns)) * rhoo/rhoi &
                                             + (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,ns))
```

260:

```
model%geometry%thck(ew,ns) = model%geometry%usrf(ew,ns) - (model%geometry%topg(ew,ns)-model%climate%eus(ew,ns))
```

174:

```
call glide_set_eus(model,eus)
```

Any help much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Seen the error message: ant_driver.f90:185.72 it looks like your free formatted code is seen as fixed formatted code and truncated after position 72 and thus missing the rest of the line. See the documentation of the compiler how to enable the free format option.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are due to line truncation.  For fixed-form Fortran a line length of 72 characters is specified and for free-form Fortran it should be 132 characters.  You source should be interpreted as free-form due to the `.f90` extension but you can force free-form in gfortran with `-ffree-form`.  You can also alter the maximum line lengths in fixed- and free-form source with the options `-ffixed-line-length-n` and `-ffree-line-length-n` respectively, where `n` is the number of characters and values of `0` or `none` mean unlimited line length.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I get the same errors even with the -ffree-form option enabled or -free-line-length-none

Comment: Does the code in any libraries or directories I am linking too also have to have --free-form by any chance? Thanks for any time in advance.